# Flutter layout issue centre of screen

Tags: flutter

how is it possible to have the following layout using flutter

2 columns 2 rows

```
column 1 row1 <Some Text> row2 <Some Text>
column 2 row1   <Button>  row2  <Button>
```

With everything centered

Thank you

Comment: you can use DataTable Widget from flutter, check this out -> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html

Comment: I cant see any reference for adding  a button. I am basically after putting a text title above each button on a row

Comment: you want to show text on a button?

Comment: Above a button.

Comment: https://ibb.co/jDc1f0r I would like text above each button

Comment: https://pastebin.com/k18Frk0R

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataTable` widget which have `DataCell` and `DataCell` child(positional argument) can be any widget. So you can use Button inside it.
Hope this will help you